# iOS UI - Toggling between UICollectionView & UITableView in one screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

The question is hopefully pretty straight forward. In one of the tabs of my application where I'm presenting a set of data from Core Data, I want to give the user the option of a Grid view or Table view. Both views should share the same custom header with a button in the header that let's them toggle.

I see it in other apps all the time, but couldn't return any searches. I'm getting stuck on how to flip between the 2 controllers based on different classes.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: simple change the view by hidding and showing the view in screen

Comment: ...or is the best approach to only use UICollectionView in a dynamic fashion whenever the toggle is hit

Comment: so do you have two controllers, one for the collectionview and one for the tableview? If not and you just maintain two views, switch between those and implement the appropriate methods

Comment: @user3358845 Yes you can achive this with the help of collectionview alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, just adjust the `itemSize` property of your items to be the width of their containing view.

Bam. Instant "table view"

Sure, it's not quite a tableView, and reasonable people can disagree over when a tableView might be more appropriate than a collectionView, but for what you describe (giving the user a choice between rows or grid), it's probably the magic bullet you seek.